# RegEx for WordPress file

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to recognize a string like this one: file=2013/08/something_320x480.jpg and to replace it in JavaScript.

Here is my regex:

```
newStr = str.replace('/file=\d+\/\d+\/.+\d+x\d+.jpg/', 'irrelevant');
```

I also tried

```
newStr = str.replace('/file=.+\.jpg/', 'irrelevant');
```

However, my string is never replaced. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regexp literal does not take apostrophes.
Try:

```
newStr = str.replace(/file=\d+\/\d+\/.+\d+x\d+.jpg/, 'irrelevant');
```

Comment: Damn, what a rookie mistake :( Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the file is set as you say it is?  I just tried your example in the console and it works...

```
> var a = "file=2013/08/something_320x480.jpg"
undefined
> a.replace(/^file=\d+\/\d+\/.+\d+x\d+.jpg$/, 'irrelevant');
"irrelevant"
```

*Update:*  I didn't spot that you had apos' in your regex, well spotted @Taemyr